# Using a Shiny slider to control output on a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am a complete novice with R and Shiny.

I have been trying to develop a tool to explore economic data. I am using GDP index data. So far the tool allows you to load different sectors but I would like to control for years as well. Here is what the [GDP Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccizS.png) looks like at the moment.

I want to use the slider to control the years as they appear on the plot.

This is the code I have so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
GDPData = read.csv("Data/GDP_Data_New.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    tags$h1("Scottish GDP by Sector")

  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Broad Sectors", 
               plotOutput("Highlevel"),
               sliderInput("SectorTime", "Select a time period", min = 1998, max = 2016,
                           value = c(1998,2016)),
               checkboxGroupInput("Indicator","Select an indicator:",   
                                  c("Total" = "Total ", "Production" = "Production", "Construction" = "Construction","Services" = "Services", "Agriculture, forestry and fishing" = "AFF"),
                                  selected = "Total ")),
      tabPanel("Production", 
               plotOutput("Production"),
               checkboxGroupInput("ProductionIndicator","Select an indicator:",   
                                  c("Total" = "Production", "Manufacturing" = "Manufacturing", "Mining and Quarrying" = "Mning","Electricity & Gas Supply" = "Electricty", "Water Supply & Waste Management" = "WaterWaste"),
                                  selected = "Production")),
      tabPanel("Services",
               plotOutput("Services"),
               checkboxGroupInput("ServicesIndicator","Select an indicator:",   
                                  c("Total" = "Services", "Distribution, Hotels and Catering" = "Distribution","Transport, Storage and Communication" = "Transport", "Business Services and Finance" = "Professional","Government, and Other Services" = "Public"),
                                  selected = "Services"))
               )

    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  SectorsData=reactive({
    return(GDPData[GDPData$Sector%in%input$Indicator,])
    })
  ProductionData=reactive({
    return(GDPData[GDPData$Sector%in%input$ProductionIndicator,])
  })
  ServicesData=reactive({
    return(GDPData[GDPData$Sector%in%input$ServicesIndicator,])
  })

  output$Highlevel <- renderPlot(ggplot(SectorsData(), aes(x=Year, y=Index, group=Sector, colour=Sector)) + geom_line()+geom_point()+theme_minimal())
  output$Production <- renderPlot(ggplot(ProductionData(), aes(x=Year, y=Index, group=Sector, colour=Sector)) + geom_line()+geom_point()+theme_minimal())
  output$Services <- renderPlot(ggplot(ServicesData(), aes(x=Year, y=Index, group=Sector, colour=Sector)) + geom_line()+geom_point()+theme_minimal())
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The CSV file has three columns "Sector","Year","Index"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: we don't have access to Data/GDP_Data_New.csv. Use dput(head(GDPData)) and put the content in your post.

Comment: You could try adding `coord_cartesian(xlim = input$SectorTime)` to all of your plots.

Comment: coord_cartesian(xlim = input$SectorTime) worked perfectly! Thank you @MikkoMarttila

Comment: use input$SectorTime and set a constraint on the values of your data set, before plotting

Answer (score 0):

here is an Example of what you need to do:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
sliderInput(inputId = "year", label = "YEAR", min = 1900, max = 2000, value = c(1920, 1980), step = 5)
,
plotOutput("plot")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  main_data <- reactive({
    data.frame(a= 1900:2000, b=rnorm(101) )
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    df <- main_data()
   df <-  df[df$a>input$year[1] & df$a<input$year[2],]
    plot(df$a, df$b, type = "l")
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```